# « Être dans la rue » pour « à la rue » ?

Tags: prépositions, québec, france, belgique, suisse

Au Québec, on trouve bon nombre d'exemples de la locution « être dans la rue », plutôt qu'avec la préposition [*à*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rue), pour « être en situation d'itinérance » ou pour différents degrés de cette situation (par exemple [ici](https://www.lapresse.ca/recherche?q=%22%C3%AAtre%20dans%20la%20rue%22#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%22%C3%AAtre%20dans%20la%20rue%22&gsc.page=2), beaucoup [moins](https://www.lapresse.ca/recherche?q=%22%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A0%20la%20rue%22#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=%22%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A0%20la%20rue%22&gsc.page=1) avec *à*, mais recherche incomplète ; le sens concret reste entier). Au LBU14 § 1049 on dit « *à la rue* pour quelqu'un qui est sans logis, dans la misère ».

1. Au Québec l'emploi de l'une ou l'autre des prépositions (*à, dans*)
   change-t-il le registre de la locution ; quel est/sont ce(s)
   registre(s) ?
2. Connaît-on cet emploi avec *dans* ailleurs (qu'au Québec) ?
3. Entendrait-on avec le sens en question « être en (la) rue » en Belgique, en Suisse ou dans l'Est de la France ?

Answer (score 2):

C'est un emploi qui est en effet utilisé au Québec et qui change, comme tu t'en doutais, de registre dépendamment de comment il est utilisé. On utilise plusieurs expressions, je vais tenter de les catégoriser.

**Langue populaire**

*Être dans la rue*: "Y'é dans rue, osti! Sacres-y patience!" (lorsque seul, besoin d'émotion, sinon c'est ambigu).

**Langue familière**

*[...] être dans la rue*: "Il est à deux pas d'être dans la rue" ou "Il vas finir par être dans la rue".

*Se ramasser dans la rue*: "Si tu continues comme ça, tu vas te ramasser dans la rue!".

**Langue standard**

*Vivre dans la rue*: "Cet homme vit dans la rue" (probablement l'expression la plus utilisée).

**Langue soutenue**

*Être à la rue*: "Il est à la rue, ce pauvre homme" (on entendrait jamais ça à l'oral).

Comment: Haha encore une fois, je m'exprime d'une manière qui fait que c'est pas trop clair, je veux dire _dans rue_ vs. _dans LA rue_, _à rue_ vs. _à LA rue_... je veux dire quasiment pas prononcer _la_. En d'autres mots est-ce que _vivre dans la rue_ et dire _vivre dans rue_ sont du même registre. Comme j'ai dit ça fait pas partie de la question, juste curieux de savoir généralement ce que tu en penses.

Comment: @λyoyed'oncques Ah! En effet à l'oral le "la" est souvent omis et c'est beaucoup plus clair. Quand le langage familier est écrit, je crois que le "la" est rajouté, mais ça devient mélangeant sans contexte, donc c'est à éviter selon moi. On pourrait potentiellement même le considérer comme dans le registre populaire.